# Implementing Django style API, chaining dots, inheritance

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement client for JSON API. I've worked with Django and i found the way it handles queries pretty interesting.

For example:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='johndoe')
>>> user
<User: johndoe>
>>> user.objects.get(username='johndoe')
AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via User instances
```

I'm interested what *Manager* exactly is and if there is a simple way to implement it. I tried to do something similar, but failed miserably. Here is my first attempt:

```
class Api(object):
    def __init__(self, api_key):
        self.api_key = key

    @property
    def player(self):
        return Player(api=self)

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api

    def get(self, id_):
        '''
        gets json and turns it into dictionary
        '''
        self.name = data['name']
        self.id_ = id_

        return self
```

So the usage would look like this:

```
>>> api = Api('api_key_here')
>>> player = api.player.get('player_id_here')
```

However to me it feels sketchy and simply wrong to do it this way(which is certainly true). Problems here are:

1. I have to send whole Api object to Player object
2. Player object will still have get() method
3. I don't know if using @property this way is acceptable

Here is how i would like to use my Api class:

```
api = Api('api_key_here')
player = api.player.get('player_id') #getting player object
item = api.item.get('item_id') #getting item object
recent_games = api.recent_games.filter(player=player, how_many=10) #getting list of game objects
```

Comment: @e4c5 Yes i did. The problem is i understand how it works in django, but i want to create json api client, which has nothing to do with django at all. I just mentioned django because i liked how you can call methods by chaining attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you look at https://github.com/samgiles/slumber which implements exactly what you may be doing (a Rest API Client). But even if you are doing something else, slumber is implemented doing what you are trying to do. Something like:

```
class RestResource(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self._store = kwargs

    def __call__(self, id=None, action=None):
       """
       Returns a new instance of self modified by one or more of the available
       parameters. These allows us to do things like override format for a
       specific request, and enables the api.resource(ID).get() syntax to get
       a specific resource by it's ID.
       """

       kwargs = {
          'foo': self._store['name1'],
          'bar': self._store['name2']
       }

       return self.__class__(**kwargs)

class Api(object):
   resource_class = RestResource

   def __getattr__(self, item):
      kwargs = {
        'name1': 'val1',
        'name2': 'val2'
      }

      return self.resource_class(**kwargs)
```

and you can use like this

```
api = Api()
api.player.get()
```

Comment: I understand how Api class works in this example, however how am i supposed to implement get() method this way if it varies depending on object(Player/Game) i want to get? Am i supposed to implement a mutual get() method inside RestResource class which recognizes what attribute i called in Api object and then return specific instance?